# Unable to change footer using wp_footer action hook

Tags: plugin-development, actions

I am learning Wordpress from a book and while learning about how to use  action hooks the author gives the below code . I am assuming this would change the footer at the front end .

```
<?php
function boj_example_footer_message() {
echo 'This site is built using < a href="http://wordpress.org"
title=”WordPress publishing platform” > WordPress < /a > .';
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'boj_example_footer_message', 100 );

?>
```

To test this out I created a plugin and had the above code put in the main plugin file . However , upon activation I get

```
"The plugin generated 8 characters of unexpected output during activation. "
```

What causes this ? What is the correct way to echo to the front end on an action hook ? How to make this work ?

Comment: This can be caused by a few things.  Typically, the cause is whitespace before or after the PHP tags.  A good habit is to not use the optional closing PHP tag `?>`. Check the answers to this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074477/the-plugin-generated-x-characters-of-unexpected-output-during-activation-wordpr

Comment: Thanks the error on activation went away upon removing the closing PHP tag . but still it doesnt change the footer . May be I am missing something

Comment: There could be another problem with the way your plugin is setup.  When I copy your function and action hook to a test site (in the functions.php file), the echo statement is firing fine.

Comment: It could be a problem with smart quotes - the ones around the title. Try pasting the straight quotes like the ones around the url.

Comment: I just tried it in several plugins including Hello Dolly too and it works for me. I concur with @jdm2112 that there must be some other problem with your plugin.

Comment: I removed the quotes and tried it both as a plugin and in functions.php of my active theme but its not working . I wished there were some ways to troubleshoot this .

Comment: There are methods to troubleshoot.  Follow the steps to enable debugging, or find your PHP error log.  You need to see what errors or warnings are being thrown but not displayed.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble people and thanks for  all your help . I am unsure how things work in the front end in WP  but found the echo from the hook in the source code at the front end . May be the theme doesnt show it .  I will surely looking into debugging and error logs .